# The best constant in an inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A, B$ are positive definite matrices of order $n$, what is the smallest constant $c$ such that $\det(A^2+B^2)\le c\det(A+B)^2$?

Comment: If such $c$ does not exist, it must depend on the size $n$.

Comment: Have you tried the case where $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable? Might be an easy first step.

Comment: @RahulNarain: When AB=BA, we may take $c=1$. I guess, generally, $c>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such $c$.  Consider the $2 \times 2$ positive definite matrices (for $t \ne 0$)
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & t^2\cr}, \ B = \pmatrix{1 & t\cr t & 2 t^2\cr}$$
Then $$\dfrac{\det(A^2 + B^2)}{\det(A+B)^2} = {\dfrac {1+7\,{t}^{2}+{t}^{4}}{25 {t}^{2}}} \to \infty \ \text{as}\ t \to 0$$

Comment: Isn't the determinant of $A+B$ in this case $5t^2$, and so the denominator should actually be $25t^4$, giving a constant ratio as $t\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: The answer is correct.

Comment: Yes $\det(A+B) = 5 t^2$, but $\det(A^2+B^2)$ also has a factor of $t^2$.